# How to pass a parameter or a value to reporting service report using visual studio report viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have a reporting service report that I want to pass some values from my application to it and show them statically. How I can pass them? Should I use paramaeter or variable? and how pass value? thanks alot

Comment: How would you expect to use the value passed to the report? We need more context in order to help you with your problem.

Comment: I get values from user to show them in `Header` and some values for compare and change formatting of some cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should use a parameter. From there, you can pass values into that parameter two different ways. You can use the API to set the parameter server side as shown here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252178%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Also, you can just build up query string arguments and pass values into a reports parameters as well:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155391.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should investigate using SSRS REService and RSService to do this!